# Can custom elements' attributes be camelCased?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I have a custom element with attributes:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    ...
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["camelCaseAttribute"];
    }

    set camelCaseAttribute(a) {
        this._a = a;
    }
    ...
 }
```

I use it in my HTML like so:

```
<my-element camelCaseAttribute="blubb"></my-element>
```

The attribute `camelCaseAttribute` is not set when writing it in camelCase, but writing it without upper-case-letters works. Why?

Comment: What kind of framework do you use? This matters

Comment: @maxkoryukov they are using HTML new technology that allows you to extend `HTMLElements` to create your own html elements

Comment: I'm using vanilla custom-elements. Except some polyfills for browsers that don't support webcomponents, its all vanilla. The polyfills are this https://github.com/webcomponents

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the **[HTML Living Standard, Section 4.13.3 Core Concepts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements-core-concepts)**:

> #### 4.13.3 Core concepts
>
> Any namespace-less attribute that is relevant to the element's functioning, as determined by the element's author, may be specified on an [autonomous custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#autonomous-custom-element), **so long as the attribute name is [XML-compatible](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible) and contains no [ASCII upper alphas](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-upper-alpha)**. The exception is the `is` attribute, which must not be specified on an [autonomous custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#autonomous-custom-element) (and which will have no effect if it is).

It is defined in the HTML Living Standard that a custom element's namespace-less attributes must be XML-compatible with no ASCII uppercase letters, thus your attributes cannot be camelCased.

Answer (score 1):

This link may help: [HTML spec says this about data attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage//dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.

Comment: But this isn't a `data-*` attribute.